# Is there out of the box Agile process templates to upload in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

I am trying to configure planning tools to use the Backlog and Board features in TFS 2015.  I am getting 7 warnings and 2 errors when I try to configure features and click the Verify button.  Years ago a developer was playing with the work item types but none of the work the developer did is valid.  It's preventing me from configuring features.  Here is the list of warning and errors when trying to configure features.

> [Warning]TF400609: Cannot add the action
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork' to the work item type 'Task'
>   because the state 'New' does not exist.
>
> [Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork' to the work item type 'Task' because
>   the state 'New' does not exist.
>
> [Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork' to the work item type 'Bug' because
>   the state 'New' does not exist.
>
> [Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork' to the work item type 'Bug' because
>   the state 'New' does not exist.
>
> [Warning] VS402404: Bugs On TaskBoard: Bug does not have the
>   Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity field defined. Some charts will not
>   include these work item types.
>
> [Warning] VS402404: Bugs On TaskBoard: Bug does not have the
>   Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork field defined. Some charts
>   will not include these work item types.
>
> [Warning] TF400607: Category 'Microsoft.HiddenCategory' will be
>   overwritten.
>
> [Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following
>   element contains an error: RequirementBacklog/Columns.  TF400529: This
>   element defines the columns that appear on the backlog. You must set
>   all values to fields that exist in at least one of the work item types
>   belonging to the category.  The following fields do not exist in any
>   of the work item types: Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea.
>
> [Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following
>   element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems.  TF400506:This
>   element defines the states for work items that represent Bugs or
>   Defects. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types
>   that are defined in: BugWorkItems.  The following states do not exist
>   in any of the work item types: New.

I am wondering if I can upload the "out of the box" agile process
templates for TFS 2015.

On a side note, when I download the Agile Process Template using the Process Template Manager in Visual Studio 2013 and then immediately
try to upload the same templates (without any changes) I get the following error:

> Exception Message: TF237070: Importing the definition failed. The
>   definition you are trying to import did not validate against the
>   schema. Edit the definition, then try toimport it again.

So I am not even sure I will be able to upload the "out of the box" agile process templates.

Thanks in advance for any insight into my issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, to manage the process template. You should need to open the same version of Visual Studio or Team Explorer as the on-premises TFS that you connect to. For example, if you connect to a TFS 2015 instance, you must connect from Visual Studio 2015 or Team Explorer 2015.

According to the error info TF400654, this error is mentioned in MSDN link [Resolve errors received when configuring features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913787.aspx), please try the related resolution:

1. [Export process configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413.aspx) using **witadmin**
   exportprocessconfig.
2. Change the `States` elements and add the missing field or state to match your work items states.
3. Then [export categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273721.aspx) and all categories matches your workflow
   requirements.
4. Finally import them after changes.